# Наложить png изображение на другую картинку через openCV на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Уже несколько дней не могу понять, как наложить два изображения друг на друга через OpenCv. Нашёл один способ, но он работает только с изображениями одного размера, а в моём случае они **разного размера**. Как сделать так, чтобы картинка нормально вставлялась в определённом месте (в координатах)? P.S Сейчас использую Pil, но он долго генерирует картинку(

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def blend_transparent(face_img, overlay_t_img):
    overlay_img = overlay_t_img[:, :, :3]
    overlay_mask = overlay_t_img[:, :, 3:]

    background_mask = 255 - overlay_mask

    overlay_mask = cv2.cvtColor(overlay_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    background_mask = cv2.cvtColor(background_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    face_part = (face_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask * (1 / 255.0))
    overlay_part = (overlay_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (overlay_mask * (1 / 255.0))

    return np.uint8(cv2.addWeighted(face_part, 255.0, overlay_part, 255.0, 0.0))


face_img = cv2.imread("bg.png")
overlay_t_img = cv2.imread("Arthor.png", -1)

result_2 = blend_transparent(face_img, overlay_t_img)
cv2.imwrite("merged_transparent.png", result_2)
```

Comment: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Покажите ваш код, чтобы было о чём говорить

Comment: думаете опнцв будет быстрее?

Comment: Добавил тот пример, который нашёл в просторах интернета и который хоть как-то работает, но только с картинками одинакового размера. Можно это как-то исправить?